# Visual Basic: Run-time error '9': "Subscript out of range"

Tags: vba, excel, basic

I'm trying to make a script, that can remove duplicates in a list of numbers. Only problem, is I keep getting `Subscript out of range (Error 9)`.

```
Sub remDupes()
Dim units() As Variant
For i = 2 To 37
    Dim var As String
    If ((Not Not units) = 0) Then
        For x = 0 To 36
            var = Cells(i, 22).Value
            If (units(x) = var) Then
                Range("V" & i, "AA" & i).Value = ""
            Else
                units(x) = var
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

The errors occurs at:

```
If (units(x) = var) Then
```

And I am not sure why

Comment: Units is a variable size array, you need to give it a size before saving value in it. Use `Dim units(0 to 36) As Variant`.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but either the `RemoveDuplicates` method of the `Range` object, or using either a `Collection` or `Dictionary` object, might be a better way to go.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thank you! I've been looking around for quite some hours now, and you're the first to suggest that.

Comment: @MathiasFrandsen Give one of those methods a try and, if you run into problems, edit your original question to ask for help; if not, you can post your results as an answer to your own question.

Comment: `If ((Not Not units) = 0) Then`makes no sense to me. What is it used for ? The actual code creates an empty Array of size 0.  Try `Ìf Len(Join(units))>0 then`

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add the following line below before the line that triggered the error.

```
ReDim Preserve units(0 To x)
```

The new code will look like this.

```
Sub remDupes()
Dim units() As Variant
For i = 2 To 37
    Dim var As String
    If ((Not Not units) = 0) Then
        For x = 0 To 36
            var = Cells(i, 22).Value
            ReDim Preserve units(0 To x)
            If (units(x) = var) Then
                Range("V" & i, "AA" & i).Value = ""
            Else
                units(x) = var
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I doesn't clean up my dupes, but it doesn't report the error anymore.